# Unable to accept meeting requests

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007

One of my VPs has an issue where when she receives an update to a meeting she is unable to accept the meeting change because it says "As the meeting Organizer you do not need to respond to this meeting request".

She is not the meeting organizer and the changes to the meeting time are not coming from her but from somebody else (Often the Executive admin, sometimes her directors).    A side effect of this is her calendar doesn't update either (since there wasn't any need to apply a change it now thinks was already done)

Normally seems to occur to reoccurring meetings and it has been very consistent for the last few months.

I have made sure the display name isn't matching anybody else so that is out.
I have completely deleted out her Outlook profile and all files, reinstalled Outlook and rebuilt the profiles from scratch to rule out a messed up OST/PST.
Nothing special or unique about her exchange profile.
I'm not finding much from Microsoft in my searches or other sources so I'm scrambling for ideas.

This is with Exchange 2003 and Outlook 2007

Any ideas?

Edit:
A few weeks ago I deleted everything involving her account.  Exported her entire email account out to a PST, deleted the AD account, purged the exchange account. reimaged both laptops that she has as well as master clearing the phone.  I also deleted out the sync profile in the Mobile Admin on exchange.  Rebuilt her from scratch, attached her old pst into a separate account.

It held for a while but now suddenly two different meetings seem to be having it again.

Comment: Is the organizer set up to be one of her delegates?  If the item gets created on behalf of her I believe Exchange still considers her the organizer, but not 100% positive.

Comment: Nope, The user has no delegates set.  The organizer does have permissions into her calendar though

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied the latest updates for Outlook 2007 & Exchange 2003? As well, take a look into the following [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941275).

Comment: Yep, everything has been applied and we are seeing it still